# What does "#define _GNU_SOURCE" imply?

Tags: c, posix, gnu

Today I had to use the `basename()` function, and the `man 3 basename` ([here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/basename.3.html#NOTES)) gave me some strange message:

> **Notes**
>
> There are two different versions of *basename()* - the **POSIX** version described above, and the **GNU version**, which one gets after
>
> `#define _GNU_SOURCE`
>   `#include <string.h>`

I'm wondering what this `#define _GNU_SOURCE` means: is it *tainting* the code I write with a GNU-related license? Or is it simply used to tell the compiler something like "*Well, I know, this set of functions is not POSIX, thus not portable, but I'd like to use it anyway*".

If so, why not give people different headers, instead of having to define some obscure macro to get one function implementation or the other?

Something also bugs me: how does the compiler know which function implementation to link with the executable? Does it use this `#define` as well?

Anybody have some pointers to give me?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Defining `_GNU_SOURCE` has nothing to do with license and everything to do with writing (non-)portable code. If you define `_GNU_SOURCE`, you will get:

1. access to lots of nonstandard GNU/Linux extension functions
2. access to traditional functions which were omitted from the POSIX standard (often for good reason, such as being replaced with better alternatives, or being tied to particular legacy implementations)
3. access to low-level functions that cannot be portable, but that you sometimes need for implementing system utilities like `mount`, `ifconfig`, etc.
4. broken behavior for lots of POSIX-specified functions, where the GNU folks disagreed with the standards committee on how the functions should behave and decided to do their own thing.

As long as you're aware of these things, it should not be a problem to define `_GNU_SOURCE`, but you should avoid defining it and instead define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` when possible to ensure that your programs are portable.

In particular, the things from `_GNU_SOURCE` that you should *never* use are #2 and #4 above.

Comment: Of course, everyone knows the *real* reason to define `_GNU_SOURCE` is in order to get [`strfry`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/strfry.html) and [`memfrob`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Trivial-Encryption.html#Trivial-Encryption).

Comment: [This link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) to the GNU C Library documentation provides some additional details (e.g., `#define _GNU_SOURCE` is recommended to be "the very first thing in the file, preceded only by comments").

Comment: Not as relevant but used to extend the 2GB file size limit on 32 bit targets.

Comment: @mckenzm: I think you're thinking of `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`, not `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Comment: I want to be a paid programmer for the porting of *strfry* *memfrob* and similar amenities to other platforms and tool-chains.

Comment: @user4815162342: This link is no more valid.

Comment: @user4815162342 `vasprintf` is also neat (minus the memleak if you're not careful) if you can't use `-std=c99` or `-std=c++11` for some reason.

Comment: @vesperto Agreed, with the difference that `strfry()` and `memfrob()` are more or less joke functions, whereas `vasprintf()` is genuinely useful.

Comment: Where is a list of the definitions of the _GNU_SOURCE macro?

Answer (score 22):

For exact details on what are all enabled by `_GNU_SOURCE`, documentation can help.

From the GNU documentation:

> Macro: _GNU_SOURCE
>
> If you define this macro, everything is included: ISO C89, ISO C99, POSIX.1, POSIX.2, BSD, SVID, X/Open, LFS, and GNU extensions. In the cases where POSIX.1 conflicts with BSD, the POSIX definitions take precedence.

From the Linux man page on [feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html):

> _GNU_SOURCE
>
> Defining this macro (with any value) implicitly defines
>                  _ATFILE_SOURCE, _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE, _ISOC99_SOURCE,
>                  _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED, _POSIX_SOURCE, _POSIX_C_SOURCE with
>                  the value 200809L (200112L in glibc versions before 2.10;
>                  199506L in glibc versions before 2.5; 199309L in glibc ver‐
>                  sions before 2.1) and _XOPEN_SOURCE with the value 700 (600
>                  in glibc versions before 2.10; 500 in glibc versions before
>                  2.2).  In addition, various GNU-specific extensions are also
>                  exposed.
>
> Since glibc 2.19, defining _GNU_SOURCE also has the effect of
>                  implicitly defining _DEFAULT_SOURCE.  In glibc versions
>                  before 2.20, defining _GNU_SOURCE also had the effect of
>                  implicitly defining _BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE.

**Note**: `_GNU_SOURCE` needs to be defined **before** including header files so that the respective headers enable the features. For example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
```

`_GNU_SOURCE` can be also be enabled per compilation using `-D` flag:

```
$ gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE file.c
```

(`-D` is not specific to `_GNU_SOURCE` but any macro be defined this way).

Answer (score 7):

Let me answer two further points:

> Something also bugs me: how does the compiler know which function implementation to link with the executable? Does it use this #define as well?

A common approach is to conditionally `#define` identifier `basename` to different names, depending on whether `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined. For instance:

```
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
# define basename __basename_gnu
#else
# define basename __basename_nongnu
#endif
```

Now the library simply needs to provide both behaviors under those names.

> If so, why not give people different headers, instead of having to define some obscure environment variable to get one function implementation or the other?

Often the same header had slightly different contents in different Unix versions, so there is no single right content for, say, `<string.h>` — there are many standards ([xkcd](http://xkcd.com/927/)).
There's a whole set of macros to pick your favorite one, so that if your program expects one standard, the library will conform to that.

Answer (score 6):

From some mailing list via google:

> Look at glibc's include/features.h:
>
> _GNU_SOURCE          All of the above, plus GNU extensions.
>
> Which means it enables all this:
>
> **STRICT_ANSI**, _ISOC99_SOURCE, _POSIX_SOURCE, _POSIX_C_SOURCE,
>   _XOPEN_SOURCE, _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED, _LARGEFILE_SOURCE,
>   _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE, _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=N, _BSD_SOURCE, _SVID_SOURCE

So it enables a whole lot of compiling flags for gcc

Comment: It does not affect the compiler's behavior, only what prototypes and things are visible from the headers.

Answer (score 2):

> why not give people different headers

They already got them; the headers are divided *by topic* into files, so it takes another dimension to filter.

I was looking for a signal number-to-name conversion. I found `strsignal()`, in `<string.h>`. The man page says:

```
sigabbrev_np(), sigdescr_np():
       _GNU_SOURCE                              <<< not default
strsignal():
       From glibc 2.10 to 2.31:
           _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L           <<< default, cf. XOPEN2K8 below
       Before glibc 2.10:
           _GNU_SOURCE
```

I had never really cared for this part at all. `sigabbrev_np()` is **not** included in the default "features". `string.h` shows how:

```
#ifdef  __USE_XOPEN2K8
/* Return a string describing the meaning of the signal number in SIG.  */
extern char *strsignal (int __sig) __THROW;

# ifdef __USE_GNU
/* Return an abbreviation string for the signal number SIG.  */
extern const char *sigabbrev_np (int __sig) __THROW;
/* Return a string describing the meaning of the signal number in SIG,
   the result is not translated.  */
extern const char *sigdescr_np (int __sig) __THROW;
# endif
```

`__USE_GNU` can/should be set via `_GNU_SOURCE`, at compilation or *top of* the file. But that "activates" all other such ifdeffed declarations in all headers, too.  (Unless you define-undefine per header)

So to explicitly import **just one** (or the other) special function, I go like this for now (copy-paste. I left the "THROW" and changed "__sig"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
extern const char *sigabbrev_np(int sig) __THROW;  /* __USE_GNU / _GNU_SOURCE */
#include <errno.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
...
```

Now `sigabbrev_np(wstate >> 8)` gives me `TRAP` etc. without #defines.

I had a hard time realizing that `0x57f` means OK because `5` is `TRAP`, but `0xb7f` and `0x77f` are `SEGV` and `BUS` --- which I got depending on where I set the breakpoint, sometimes after thousands of instructions. Because I did not step back the intruction pointer...