# Why do we need to define _GNU_SOURCE macro before using POLLRDHUP event flag in poll() function?

Tags: c, sockets, opensuse

I am using `poll()` function in my program, I read [this link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) that to use `POLLRDHUP` flag you have to define `_GNU_SOURCE` before all header file inclusion. I needed this flag so that polling the socket can tell me whether the client has hung up or not, so that I can terminate the corresponding thread.

By the way I am writing a C program for an 'echo' server which can handle multiple clients concurrently, and I am using GCC 4.1.2 on OpenSuse Linux Enterprise Server 10.3 (x86_64).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`POLLRDHUP` is a non-standard extension (it is [missing from POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)). To prevent polluting the namespace, non-standard extensions are not visible unless you explicitly request them by [defining `_GNU_SOURCE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#index-g_t_005fGNU_005fSOURCE-51).

More details on `_GNU_SOURCE` can be found in previous StackOverflow answers [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5583764/1600898).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the details of `_GNU_SOURCE` on the given link.

Comment: The given link also recommends to make `#define _GNU_SOURCE` "the very first thing in the file, preceded only by comments".

Answer (score 2):

`_GNU_SOURCE` is a feature test macros which is useful for creating portable applications, by preventing nonstandard definitions from being exposed.