# CLONE_VM undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, linux, clone

I am using the clone feature in linux c.

However, I encountered the error CLONE_VM undeclared (first use in this function) when I tried to compile my code.

I went to google for solutions and one of the site mentioned that `#include <sched.h>` must be included inside the code. I have already included `#include <sched.h>` in my code but the compilation error still persists.

Any help? :)

```
int c = clone(child,p+STACKSIZE-1,CLONE_VM|SIGCHLD,NULL) ;
```

Comment: Don't use `clone`. Use the standard pthread library. The `clone` syscall is mostly for implementors of Posix threads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following lines to the beginning of your code

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
   #include <sched.h>
```

You could find out which header files and/or macros are needed by

- `man 2 syscall_name`
- `man 3 library_function_name`

By the way, the implication of `_GNU_SOURCE` and more could be find out by `man 7 feature_test_macros`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!
May I know what does the _GNU_SOURCE does?

Comment: Nevermind. I found my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582211/what-does-define-gnu-source-imply

Comment: @LawrenceWong You could find it out by `man 7 feature_test_macros`

Answer (score 1):

sometime including `#include <sched.h>` will not work, so point sched.h file from linux. i.e. `#include <linux/sched.h>`

Comment: For me it worked when I put "#define _GNU_SOURCE" then "#include <sched.h>" on *top* of the source code (above all other #includes).