# O_DIRECT undeclared, Eclipse CDT, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I am experiencing an issue with O_DIRECT.
I am trying to use it with `open()`, but I get an error like:

```
error: O_DIRECT undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I am including `<fcntl.h>`

I grepped `/usr/include/` directory for `O_DIRECT` and it exists in `x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h`. I tried to include this file instead, but then I get this error:

```
error: #error Never use <x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h> directly; include <fcntl.h> instead.
```

I am trying to all of this in Eclipse CDT project on newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define `_GNU_SOURCE` before including `<fcntl.h>` or add `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to your compiler command.

Note that this reduces portability of your program.

Comment: Thank you, it resolved my problem. I added _GNU_SOURCE to defined symbols in project settings in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

> it exists in x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h. I tried to include this file instead, but then I get this error

As the error says, you shouldn't include `bits` headers directly.

`O_DIRECT` is a Linux extension (i.e. not in POSIX). You need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` to get it. You can either define it at the top of source file, like:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

or define while compiling with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`. e.g.

```
gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE file.c
```

You may interested in [What does "#define _GNU_SOURCE" imply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5582211/4389800) too.

Comment: Thank you, it resolved my problem. I added _GNU_SOURCE to defined symbols in project settings in Eclipse.