# C：[Error] 'getline' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c

I have ***include<stdio.h>***, why it show that ***[Error] 'getline' was not declared in this scope ？***

what should I do? Thank you!

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_input(InputBuffer* input_buffer) {
    
    ssize_t bytes_read = 
                      getline(&(input_buffer->buffer), &(input_buffer->buffer_length), stdin);//this line show error

    if (bytes_read <= 0) {
        printf("Error reading input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    input_buffer->input_length = bytes_read - 1;
    input_buffer->buffer[bytes_read - 1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on a POSIX-compliant system?

Comment: "Both getline() and getdelim() were originally GNU extensions.
       They were standardized in POSIX.1-2008."

Comment: I am a beginner and do not what is POSIX. I am following a blog to build an easy database, then I meet this error.  I code on win10, not on Linux, my problem is on this?

Comment: @雨泉清音 Try copying [this program](https://onlinegdb.com/c9fKb6BbDq) into your IDE/editor and try compiling it. If it gives an error, `getline` is not supported on your system.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 it actually gives an error, so I need to change to work on Linux?

Comment: @雨泉清音 if you can then sure. However, there are standard alternatives to `getline`. You can create a large buffer size from before and use `fgets`. If no characters were read, a `NULL` pointer will be returned. So you can check for an error with that.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1   very very thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`man getline` says that it is defined under `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L` since glibc 2.10 and `_GNU_SOURCE` before. So try to add `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before all your includes in the beginning. If that doesn't help, also add `#define _GNU_SOURCE`. But this works for glibc only. If you are on Windows/MSVC, then use `fgets()`, just have large enough buffer to fit any line with ending newline and null terminator.

Comment: This will not work. How can a function be defined simply from a macro being defined? The real purpose of these macros is to *check the version* to see if certain features/functions exist, not to define them yourself.

Comment: Such macros affect what header files define. So you need to define one of such macros to have header file give you a definition.

Comment: Actually, maybe you're right. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582211/what-does-define-gnu-source-imply), defining `_GNU_SOURCE` provides extra features (though this would probably not work for a compiler like MSVC). I'm still not sure about `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` though. I believe that is a macro that should only be defined by the implementation to show that it is POSIX-compliant, I don't think the programmer is supposed to define it themselves. Besides, since OP is saying they're using WIndows, I doubt `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE` will have any effect at all.

Comment: yes, `_GNU_SOURCE` and all stuff behind it is glibc specific. So it won't work for the MSVC.

Comment: " since OP is saying they're using Windows" - missed that. Since `getline()` is GNU extension, then for MSVC it is not available at all. So then use `fgets()`.

Comment: It seems like I was wrong about `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` too, and that [you can define it with a certain value to get more features](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) :P I'm not sure if that applies for mingw as well though (if OP is using mingw. they may be using MSVC too, in which case both macros would be pretty useless).

Comment: mingw uses msvcrt, so unlikely it is available.