# F_GETPIPE_SZ undeclared

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to get size of pipe:

```
printf("pipe 0 size: %d bytes\npipe 1 size: %d bytes\n", fcntl(fd[0], F_GETPIPE_SZ), fcntl(fd[1], F_GETPIPE_SZ));
```

Used headers (half of them used by another parts of code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

When I'm trying to compile, **gcc** fails with this error:

> ‘F_GETPIPE_SZ’ undeclared (first use in this function)

> kernel version - 5.4.0-88-generic
>
> libc6-dev version - 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
>
> gcc version - 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2

Comment: read the man page `man fcntl`, it mentions you need the macro `__GNU_SOURCE` for `F_GETPIPE_SZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this macro is not part of POSIX, you must define the `_GNU_SOURCE` feature test macro before including `<fcntl.h>`.

This is stated in [the `fcntl(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html), in the "Conforming To" section.

See [What does "#define _GNU_SOURCE" imply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582211/what-does-define-gnu-source-imply)